Vercel deploy wont get /api second time, it save the last get
Hi Everyone thanks for reading
i have a little bit problem on building quotes project, with nextjs deployed on vercel
works fine on local but wont get the new quotes on deploy
always show the same result, i have no ideas whats could be wrong, I needed an advice
this is my /api
import axios from "axios";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { Quotable, QuoteTypes, QuoteZen } from "@/types/quotesType";

const urlWaifu = "https://waifu.it/api/v4/quote";
const urlZen = "https://zenquotes.io/api/random/";
const urlQuotable =
  "https://api.quotable.io/quotes/random?limit=1&tags=technology|famous-quotes|film|love|pain|sadness|self-help";

const list = ["Zen", "Waifu", "Quotable"];
const randomizer = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
const selected = list[randomizer];

export async function GET() {
  try {
    let response;
    let provider;
    let linkProvider;

    switch (selected) {
      case "Waifu":
        provider = "Waifu.it";
        linkProvider = "https://waifu.it/";
        response = await axios.get(urlWaifu, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: process.env.WAIFU_IT_TOKEN,
          },
        });
        break;

      case "Zen":
        provider = "ZenQuotes";
        linkProvider = "https://zenquotes.io/";
        const resZ = await axios.get(urlZen);
        const zenQuotes: QuoteZen = resZ.data[0];
        const readyZenQuotes: QuoteTypes = {
          _id: 1,
          quote: zenQuotes.q,
          anime: "",
          author: zenQuotes.a,
        };
        response = { data: readyZenQuotes };
        break;

      case "Quotable":
        provider = "Quotable Quotes";
        linkProvider = "https://github.com/lukePeavey/quotable";
        const resQ = await axios.get(urlQuotable);
        const QuotableQuotes: Quotable = resQ.data[0];
        const readyQuotableQuotes: QuoteTypes = {
          _id: QuotableQuotes._id,
          quote: QuotableQuotes.content,
          anime: "",
          author: QuotableQuotes.author,
        };
        response = { data: readyQuotableQuotes };
        break;
    }

    return NextResponse.json(
      { data: response?.data, provider: provider, linkProvider: linkProvider },
      {
        status: 200,
        headers: {
          "Cache-Control":
            "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate",
          Pragma: "no-cache",
          Expires: "0",
          "Surrogate-Control": "no-store",
        },
      }
    );
  } catch (error: any) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { error: "Error fetching quotes", details: error.message || error },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}

then i fetch it like this
 const fetchQuote = async () => {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const response = await fetch(`/api/quotes`, {
        cache: "no-store",
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
      }

      const rawData = await response.json();
      const quotesData = rawData.data;
      setQuote(quotesData);
      setProvider(rawData.provider);
      setLinkProvider(rawData.linkProvider);
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      setIsError(true);
      toast.error("Error when providing wisdom. Please try again.");
    }
  };

fetchQuote wont go more than one. The app just load it once, when fetchQuote got called again it shows the same data like before
the expected is, it should get another data/quotes
just in case I attach repo link here
Repo
thank you in advance
